# bad interpreter: No such file or directory macOS Ventura

Tags: python, macos, macos-ventura

I updated macOS to the new version Ventura 13.1 and python has stopped working

```
/Users/myuser/Library/Python/3.8/bin/pre-commit: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Running `python3` from any directory works, but I don't really understand the error after the update

```
python3
Python 3.11.1 (v3.11.1:a7a450f84a, Dec  6 2022, 15:24:06) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang- 
1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
```

Comment: Did you install the command-line tools after updating?

Comment: Note that [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) means something very specific, and it's not the type of computer.

Comment: @tadman I did not install anything else, I thought it would continue working as before, what should I install?

Comment: Usually you need to update XCode, and then install the associated "Command Line Tools" package.

Comment: xcode-select: note: install requested for command line developer tools, ok, I understand, you're right, I'm installing!

Comment: You may prefer using the [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) version as that often decouples your Python installation from your OS, and you can pick specific versions to install as well.

Comment: @tadman Everything works now! Thank you very much, if you want leave the answer to mark it so it can be useful for others!

Comment: Probably easiest to add a self-answer with what you did.